# Translate PostgreSQL conditions to mongoDB

Tags: postgresql, mongodb, activerecord, mongomapper

I have these `WHERE` conditions in a PostgreSQL query that I need to translate to mongoDB:

```
(starts_at BETWEEN :starts AND :ends) OR (starts_at <= :starts AND ends_at >= :starts)
```

Note `:starts` and `:ends` are UTC times. Specifically, I'm moving this from ActiveRecord to MongoMapper. So bonus if you can help me with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mongodb, you'd use the [$or](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or) operator like this (along with [$gte and $lte](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%3C%2C%3C%3D%2C%3E%2C%3E%3D)):

```
db.collection.find({
    $or: [
        { starts_at: { $gte: starts }, starts_at: { $lte: ends } },
        { starts_at: { $lte: starts }, ends_at: { $gte: starts } }
    ]
});
```

In MongoMapper that would translate to:

```
Model.where(
    :$or => [
        { :starts_at => { :$gte => starts, :$lte => ends } },
        { :starts_at => { :$lte => starts }, :ends_at => { :$gte => starts } }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to change your code a small bit, but it definitely got me on the right path. Here's what I wound up with that worked:   where :$or => [
        { starts_at: { :$gte => starts, :$lte => ends } },
        { starts_at: { :$lte => starts }, ends_at: { :$gte => starts } } 
      ]

Comment: @MichaelIrwin, thanks, must have been thinkos on my part ;). Teaches me to post code without seeing if it runs. Anyway, I made the update to my answer to reflect that.